# Can I use Microsoft Wireless Adapter with multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, miracast

I want my Desktop to be tucked away under my desk and would like to use 2 Monitors wirelessly with my Desktop.

Is Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter product capable of allowing my 64-bit Windows 10 PC to use Extended Desktop on 2 Monitors?

If not then what product would be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wireless HDMI, I'd recommend using Nyrius ARIES. Works very well even with gaming; however, this is a more expensive option.

To use a Microsoft Wireless Adapter for desktop, you'll likely need to get yourself an 'Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 for Desktop' so that your desktop can support Miracast (you may need to uninstall any graphic cards to use Miracast). You'll also need to have the right kind of processor to use Miracast.

Microsoft Wireless Adapter v2 is very well suitable for most tasks, with only about a 100ms delay.

It may be worthwhile to go with Microsoft Wireless Adapter v2 + Nyrius ARIES for multiple wireless monitors.

Comment: How is it that answer gets lets points than question, awesome answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your PC need Miracast-enabled video adapter and that's usually in mobile video adapters. Some latest desktop video adapters like AMD R9 290 or NVidia GTX980 can do it too.

Your PC also need WiFi-Direct-enabled network adapter, which again usually available in mobile chips.

For reference http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/miracast-support-on-custom-build-pcs/7f33822a-4aeb-40eb-b772-dac78a89d076

But even then you will not be able to connect 2 displays, WiFi-Direct work only for one device.

And even if you will be able to do it you will be disappointed. It's useful as additional display for presentation, but latency is too big to use it as main display and totally unusable even for simple action games.